# How to change post_author woocommerce when customer submit place order

Tags: woocommerce

Please help, when customer submit place order, woocommerce is saved post_author = 1. (admin)
How to change post_author = 2 when customer has completed order?
Please advise, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you need.

```
// use action woocommerce_new_order or woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'modify_new_order', 10, 1 );

function modify_new_order( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $my_post = [
       'ID'           => $order_id,
       'post_author'  => $order->user_id // user ID who created this post
    ];

   // Update the post into the database
   wp_update_post( $my_post );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful.